# No iplayer orYou tube sound

Tags: sound

Clicking Music folder gets "oops something wrong" and  reverts back to contents of Home folder.
Audio file in Pictures folder works fine with sound.
Video file in Videos works fine with sound.
Old downloaded podcast in Audacity works fine with sound.
Audacity records sounds and plays the file back.
BBC iplayer and BBC sounds do not have sound!
A recent Zoom Speed Awareness course began with no sound but after the Host's adjustments it was restored albeit by sharing the host's screen.